# How to unit test for an ORM calls or a query builder

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

So here, I have a `TeacherSubject` Model and a function declared `getAllotedSectionsToStaff($staffId, $classId)`, `section` is a relation defined in the model `TeacherSubject` . I wanted to write a unit test just to ensure the right Model is used with the right conditions and relations, without having DB connection, using mocking maybe.

```
public function getAllotedSectionsToStaff($staffId, $classId)
    {
        return TeacherSubject::where([
            'school_class_id' => $classId,
            'staff_id' => $staffId
        ])
            ->with('section')
            ->groupBy('section_id')
            ->get();
    }
```

This piece of code is from Laravel framework, any suggestions are welcome to vanilla PHP as well.
Thanks

Comment: So, you NEVER mock a model, no part at all should be mocked, you must test it with a database (you can use `in-memory`), and then, the idea is to test a feature test where you are using the relationship and see that it works

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just one quick question how can I unit test getAllotedSectionsToStaff() if I want to? Avoid using DB or any other dependency (API calls)

Comment: That model's method (`getAllotedSectionsToStaff`) is returning a Collection, but you are getting that info with a Model, hence a Query, so you need a database, you can't escape it. What is the issue of using a database?

Comment: No issues with DB. I'm working on Perl, and here I can mock the database and test the query formed, without actually getting into DB. So I was wondering if I could do something like this in PHP. Thanks @matiaslauriti

Comment: Honestly, you can mock it, but if you do that, you will not be truly testing it, because there could be some local or global scopes applied, and if you mock it, those would not run, hence not changing the original query (among other things like Casts too)